# REST API. Should I double-check phone verification code when sign up

Tags: rest, authentication, registration, verification

I have a REST Api with following path for user to register:

1. send verification code (/phone-code) -> 2. verify code (/verify) -> 3. enter personal information and register (/sign-up).

On the second step I mark phone as validated if entered code is correct and on the third step i check if phone is marked as validated. But imagine one person verifies the phone and another (let's say a hacker) tries to skip first 2 steps and triggers /sign-up with first person's phone. As the phone is already validated, a hacker registers successfully.

So the question is how to make /sign-up safe? One idea that comes to my mind is double-check code on the second and the third steps. But that comes with a coast of increasing the duration of validation code which is not very safe. Could you advise me something better?

Comment: Why don't you send the verification code after entering personal information? How can a hacker get the verification code? Did you do some sort of risk assessment? This is more like a security question instead of a programming one. It is an entirely different job, I studied both.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of session system on your service that uses cookies. When you sign up and verify, you remember the phone number and whether it was verified in the session.

You shouldn't have to ask for the phone number again, because the phone number should be known and in the session.

Comment: REST is stateless, you cannot use session cookies.

Comment: Ok. Then by a JWT you store the session information in the token. The server holds the key to check the signature and accepts it as valid. Which means you store the session = client state on the client side. In the case of session cookies the cookie is just an identifier and you store the session = client state on the server. Which makes the first stateless the second stateful communication. When the server shuts down or you change server, because you have multiple ones, then nothing happens in the first case and all the clients logout in the second case.

Comment: We use stateless communication, because after a certain amount of users e.g. a few million managing session on the server becomes a too big task. Managing sessions on the client side makes horizonal scaling a lot more easier.

Comment: The dissertation is crystal clear about this. Maybe just read it again.  "Stateless
We next add a constraint to the client-server interaction: communication must be stateless in nature, as in the client-stateless-server (CSS) style of Section 3.4.3 (Figure 5-3), such that each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client."

Comment: Sure in this case probably the questioner doesn't need it at all, because he doesn't need REST at all. Most of the cases people just add questions about REST, which are completely unrelated to REST. Just wonder then what we are talking about, because it is not the architecture style which is tagged... These REST constraints are not optional.

Comment: You think whatever you want to. :-) Tbh. it does not really matter from my perspective. Cheers!